# Identify quotient group on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $F: \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ be the homomorphism of groups given by
$$F(a)=(ma,-[a]_n)$$
with fixed $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

What is, up to isomorphism, the quotient group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_n/\mathrm{Im}(F)$

Comment: You might find it helpful to think of $F$ as the map 
$$
F(a) = a \cdot (m,[-1]_n)
$$

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide [some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for this question. For instance, tell us where you encountered the problem or what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $G : \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ given by:
$$
(x,y+n\mathbb{Z})\mapsto x+my+mn\mathbb{Z}
$$
Left to the reader: Show that this is well defined, that it is a group homomorphism, and that $\mathrm{Im}(F)\subseteq\mathrm{Ker}(G)$.

To show the other inclusion:

Suppose $G(x,y+n\mathbb{Z})=mn\mathbb{Z}$, then $x+my\in mn\mathbb{Z}$ so there is some k such that $x+my=mnk$, so $x=mnk-my=m(nk-y)$, and $y\equiv -(nk-y) \mod n$, that is $$(x,y+n\mathbb{Z})=(m(nk-y),-(nk-y)+n\mathbb{Z})=F(nk-y).$$

Now we have $\mathrm{Im}(F)=\mathrm{Ker}(G)$, so by the first isomorphism theorem we get
$$(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/\mathrm{Im}(F)\cong \mathrm{Im}(G)$$

Now $\mathrm{Im}(G)=\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ because for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $G(x,n\mathbb{Z})=x+mn\mathbb{Z}$

Note:
To get to the homomorphism above, I checked what $(x_1,y_1+n\mathbb{Z})+\mathrm{Im}(F)=(x_2,y_2+n\mathbb{Z})+\mathrm{Im}(F)$ in the quotient group means, which turned out to be (after some working out)
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&x_1\equiv x_2&&\mod m\\
&x_1+my_1\equiv x_2+my_2&&\mod mn
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

And it turned out that the first congruence follows from the second, and the second congruence gives the homomorphism defined above.